# PHP or htaccess - allow external server to check if file exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-exists

In the folder `bla.com/files/`

I got files like `1.json` `2.json`

And I try to check from another server if `1.json` exists so I do:

```
$file = 'http://www.bla.com/files/1.json';

$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
{

}
else
{

}
```

bla.com was on another server before and this code worked fine but since it's on a new server `$file_headers[0]` returns nothing any more.

How could I check if a file exists or not now? Putting htaccess with anything specific inside `bla.com/files/` folder or something? I know that I can ask the provider to activate the `allow_url_fopen` but is there another way?

Comment: Can you print out $file_headers ? Or add error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); to the script.

Comment: yes it's: bool(false)

Comment: Also remove the @ in front of get_headers to view possible errors.

Comment: I removed it and added error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE); at start but it shows nothing

Comment: Last thing I can think about is that display_errors is disabled. You can enable this by placing "php_flag display_errors on" in .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok I did but it's still not showing any errors :/

Comment: you can use `file_exists` on a url, if the wrappers are enabled

Comment: file_exists don't work that would be too easy xD